# Animation on the same two characters

Tags: animation, nla-editor, actions

I was trying to create a simple walking animation of a character in NLA. However, due to some unavoidable reason, I have to append walking animation on the same two characters once at a time. The positions of root bones of both the characters are at different locations. The same walking animation was also duplicated in Action Editor and linked in NLA with two characters. However, after doing all of the above some adverse movements on the second character is appeared, although, no problem in animation was found for the first character. A screenshot is attached. Please help. [image: Screenshot]

Comment: the bones of the second armature may not be rotated the same way?

Comment: But both the rig are ditto and the Animation used for both the rig are also exactly same.

Comment: Looking at the second character, it looks like its FK legs are animating correctly, but is using the IK legs instead. Try setting it to FK maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Check if IK foot are child of Root bone (IK parent n. 1, default).

[image]